How to assign an initial value for an input from a calculation from another inputs and parameters?
My problem is that I need to assign the initial value from another input and parameters, and then export to FMU. In OMEdit I can check the code and it doesnt give any trouble, but, if I try to export to FMU, it gives these errors:
Internal error BackendDAE.adjacencyRowEnhanced failed for eqn:

algorithm:
Pref := pgt * R + w - wref;

Translation Error:
Internal error BackendDAEUtil.getAdjacencyMatrixEnhancedScalar failed

Here is what a simplified version of my code looks like:
model text_example;
    parameter Real R = 0.04;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput Pref;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput pgt;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput w;
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput wref(start=1);
    Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput pt;
    Modelica.Blocks.Math.Add add1(k1=1,k2 = -1)
    initial algorithm
        Pref:=pgt*R+(w-wref);
    equation
        connect(Pref,add1.u1);
        connect(w,add1.u2);
        connect(add1.y,pt);
end test_example;

I use this in DIgSILENT PowerFactory via FMU export from OMEdit, so pgt and w come from the simulation, and Pref and wref are reference values that may change if an event is set up.
